# Lua table syntax

Tags: lua, lua-table

This seems to be legitimate Lua syntax:

`example = { ["dummy"] = "foobar"}`

Why would you use the above and not simply:

`example = { dummy = "foobar"}`

They appear to functionally the same...

Comment: It was surprising for me that I can't write, for example, `t = { in=0, out=1, err=2 }`

Comment: Surprising that you *can't* write? @egorskriptunoff it looks valid to me

Comment: @warspyking `in` is a keyword, so it can't be used as a table field name without brackets.

Comment: Oh LOL totally didn't see that @colonel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because field names do not have to be identifiers: they can be any string, including strings having spaces, for instance.

The second statement is valid Lua syntax and is very convenient for field names that are identifiers.

Table keys do not have to be strings: they can actually be any value (except nil) and the `[expr]=expr` syntax for table entries allows the values of arbitrary expressions to be used as keys.

Comment: Can they be *any* value except nil? I'm pretty sure there's another one.

Comment: except nil and nan.